# How to place DIVs beside each other

Tags: html, css

I have several DIVs that I want to place beside each other, but because they are blocking, they fall beneath each other. How can I fix this?

Comment: As stated in a number of the answers, it'd be a good idea to include your code.  With your question as it stands now, there are a number of valid answers but it's impossible for anyone to identify the _best_ answer for your situation without more detail in your question.  And welcome to SO :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to use float:left, but in some cases you might use SPAN instead of DIV

Comment: Nooooo floats are evil. As in, they cause a lot more problems than they solve.

Comment: They collapse the element out of the layout. They're perfect for their original, intended usage: floating things next to long runs of text (think pictures in a book). But they were never meant as a layout mechanism, and so abusing them leads to all sorts of icky stuff like the infamous "clearfix".

Comment: Ah, so they're not evil per se! Just like tables and blockquotes and horizontal rules, they have their place. As long as you don't abuse them.

Comment: Right. But putting divs next to each other is abuse.

Answer (score 4):

```
div.i-like-snuggling {
    /* don't ever leave me */
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with the following code:

style="display:inline-block";

EDIT

for your edification:http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_styles.asp

Comment: i never heard of an attribute `stytle`. Is this `HTML6`?

Comment: @Liam Dear Liam, you are a bit out-of-date: [html6](http://blog.whatwg.org/html6-plan)

Comment: @Christoph I'll believe it when a browser actually supports it?! :) Whats the penertration of HTML5? How many users still use IE5, etc. Still interesting though. First I've heard of it!

Comment: @Liam look at the date on that post :)

Answer (score 1):

Or maybe absolute positioning is the best choice for you. We don't know what your HTML looks like!

Comment: I like this guy! (and absolute positioning...)

Answer (score 0):

add `display: inline-block;` style to those divs

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to go with the css property "float"

```
div { float: left; width: 200px}
```

for example. If you don't specify a width, the browser will render a width that it feels appropriate (the width of a child element for example).

I've always found this article a good reference: http://css.maxdesign.com.au/floatutorial/introduction.htm

As suggested by other people, you can also use `display:inline-block`. It kinda depends on what effect you want to achieve.

Comment: And you may have problems if the divs are not the same height, or they have special margin/padding needs...

Comment: True, it'd be interesting to know more details about what Petter Hermansen is trying to achieve.